# Getting Error with java autoboxing

Tags: java, autoboxing

Can anyone tell why the auto boxing is not working, and why with constructor it works fine:

```
int intValue = 12;
Double FirstDoubleValue = new Double(intValue);
Double SecondDoubleValue = intValue; // ==> Error
```

Thanks for advance :)

Comment: You can't combine auto-boxing with other implicit conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The constructor expects a `double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double%28double%29), **a primitive type**, in which case, through [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), an `int` can be used.

However, in

```
Double SecondDoubleValue = intValue; // ==> Error
```

you're trying to assign an `int` to a `Double`. Those are incompatible types.

Note that [boxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> converts expressions of primitive type to
>   corresponding expressions of reference type

so an `int` would become an `Integer`, but `Integer` is still not compatible with `Double`.

Comment: So the auto boxing doesn't use implicitly the wrapper class constructor?

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode That's not specified as far as I can tell. As far as I've seen, it typically uses the `static valueOf` method of the corresponding reference type. Note that it still wouldn't make any difference, because it would use `Integer.valueOf(..)`, not `Double.valueOf(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Double SecondDoubleValue = (double)intValue;
```

Java cannot cast int to Double. It can cast int to double, which is what is happening on your second line.

Look here for some in depth answers about conversions.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: I won't down-vote, but I just deleted my answer which stated the same exact thing. He knows how to do it. He's asking why it's necessary.